# How to make left,right,up,down window movement behave like if windows were a ring?

Tags: vim-windows, movement

This is, in the current window layout:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
| A | D | C |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
| E | F | G |
+---+---+---+
```

If the focused windows is `A`, then moving to the left should move to `C` windows. If we are in `C`, then moving to the right should move to `A`.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

1. Try to move to window in `<direction>`
2. If successful: done (it was not a boundary window)
3. Else: move to the window in the extreme opposite of `<direction>`

```
function! CircularMove(wincmd) abort
  let previous_winnr = winnr()
  silent! execute "wincmd " . a:wincmd
  let directions = {'h': 'l', 'j': 'k', 'k': 'j', 'l': 'h'}
  if previous_winnr == winnr()
    silent! execute '200' 'wincmd' directions[a:wincmd]
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <C-h> :silent call CircularMove('h')<CR>
nnoremap <C-l> :silent call CircularMove('l')<CR>
```

N.B.  This will render plugins like vim-tmux-navigator unusable.